# Python Loop only writing to last row

Tags: python, for-loop

I am opening an excel spreadsheet, reading the data in column b and using that data performing a URL lookup and regex on the page then saving the data found into columns 3 and 4 on the same spreadsheet. Everything works okay but it's only writing the last row. I think because of how my for loops are structured, I have searched numerous topics on here but haven't been able to fathom it yet.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import urllib
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
directoryPath=r'C:\Python27' #The main folder
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list=os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath): #Traversing the sub folders
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename = os.path.join(folders, name)
            wb=load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
            ws=wb.active
            cell_range = ws['B2':'B4']
            f = urllib.urlopen(cell.value)
            s = f.read()
            for row in cell_range: # This is iterating through rows 1-7
                for cell in row: # This iterates through the columns(cells) in that row
                    ws.cell(row=ws._current_row, column=3).value= str(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s))
                    ws.cell(row=ws._current_row, column=4).value= str(re.findall(r"\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)",s))
                    wb.save('scraper.xlsx')
```

example urls to test with

```
http://www.knaptoninsurance.co.uk/contact-us
http://www.sterlingsafetywear.co.uk/contact
http://www.ilu.org.uk/contact.html
```

Comment: `wb.save('scraper.xlsx')`  should not be within the loop

Comment: Why are you storing Excel files in your Python installation directory?

Comment: This is just still in dev work, once it's working fine it will live in it's own proper place. Also taking out wb.save('scraper.xlsx') didn't solve it.

Comment: As J-F-F points out above, the problem is that you are saving the workbook each time the loop runs, so you will only ever se the saved version from the last iteration.

Comment: I see, I tried breaking out of the loops and then saving the workbook but that didn't seem to work, would you advise this?